# get the quantity of equal id sections with python in json

Tags: python

This is my code i would get the quantity of the sections if in json 1 there are equal id sections in json 2.
Help me to get the quantity of the sections only if in json 1 there are sections that have the id in json 2.
[i get this but not the right amount](https://i.stack.imgur.com/stdPN.png)

I would like to get something like this https://fn-api.com/api/shop/br/sections?lang=it

```py
import requests


#--------FORTNITEDATA--------#
response = requests.get(f"https://fortnitecontent-website-prod07.ol.epicgames.com/content/api/pages/fortnite-game/shop-sections?lang=it")
data = response.json()["sectionList"]['sections']
newlist = []
#--------ENDFORTNITEDATA--------#

#--------TIMELINE--------#
timeline = requests.get("https://api.nitestats.com/v1/epic/modes")
try:
    timelinedata = timeline.json()['channels']['client-events']['states'][1]['state']['sectionStoreEnds']
except:
    pass 
try:
    timelinedata = timeline.json()['channels']['client-events']['states'][0]['state']['sectionStoreEnds']
except:
    pass
#--------ENDTIMELINE--------#


def section():
    for sections in data:
        for i in timelinedata:      
            if i in sections['sectionId']:
                try:
                   if sections["sectionDisplayName"] not in newlist:
                      newlist.append(sections["sectionDisplayName"])
                      print(f'{sections["sectionDisplayName"]}\n')
                except:
                    pass                                  


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("SEZIONI DEL NEGOZIO\n")
    while True:
        section()
        exit()
```

Comment: to count how many of something there is, you can use a [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), you just need to feed it the something

Comment: I mean not a specification must give the result of the quantity of all sections that are active in timelinedata = timeline.json()['channels']['client-events']['states'][0]['state']['sectionStoreEnds']  example here https://i.imgur.com/yOWYJYn.png

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you want to get, but your `section` function can also be express in a list comprehension

```
>>> pair=[(sections.get("sectionDisplayName"),sections['sectionId']) for sections in data if sections['sectionId'] in timelinedata ]
>>> pair
[('Squadra S.T.A.R.S.', 'Re'),
 ('In evidenza', 'Featured'),
 ('Ogni giorno', 'Daily'),
 ('Ariana Grande cosmonauta', 'SpacefarerB'),
 ('Ariana Grande', 'ArianaB'),
 ('A tutta pittura', 'InThePaintB'),
 ('A tutta pittura', 'InThePaint2B'),
 ('Dune', 'DuneB'),
 ('Offerte da brividi', 'SpookyOffers'),
 ('Offerte da brividi', 'SpookyOffers2'),
 ('Offerte da brividi', 'SpookyOffers3')]
>>>
```

Here I pair together the "sectionDisplayName" with their 'sectionId' so long the latter is in timelinedata.
we avoid the need of a try-except block by using the [.get](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) method given that we are working with dictionaries.

Now we can count the part we want to count

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter( a for a,b in pair)
Counter({'Offerte da brividi': 3,
         'A tutta pittura': 2,
         'Squadra S.T.A.R.S.': 1,
         'In evidenza': 1,
         'Ogni giorno': 1,
         'Ariana Grande cosmonauta': 1,
         'Ariana Grande': 1,
         'Dune': 1})
>>>
```

if this pairing thing if not necessary, then a few adjustments will suffice

```
>>> singles=[sections.get("sectionDisplayName") for sections in data if sections['sectionId'] in timelinedata ]
>>> singles
['Squadra S.T.A.R.S.',
 'In evidenza',
 'Ogni giorno',
 'Ariana Grande cosmonauta',
 'Ariana Grande',
 'A tutta pittura',
 'A tutta pittura',
 'Dune',
 'Offerte da brividi',
 'Offerte da brividi',
 'Offerte da brividi']
>>> Counter(singles)
Counter({'Offerte da brividi': 3,
         'A tutta pittura': 2,
         'Squadra S.T.A.R.S.': 1,
         'In evidenza': 1,
         'Ogni giorno': 1,
         'Ariana Grande cosmonauta': 1,
         'Ariana Grande': 1,
         'Dune': 1})
>>>
```

Comment: thanks for your help with some sections I get None https://i.imgur.com/q50tRHe.png 
i know why Featured2 doesn't have Featured by default but i don't know how to fix it

Comment: None is the value you get when when you use the .get method when the key isn't present in the dict, you can provided it with a default value of your choosing for when that happens or to skip those include a check for that key in the condition in the if statement